# Extracting matching values between arrays and saving them into a new array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm quite new to programming and I'm trying to complete the following exercise:

Declare a new variable to store all the a1 extracted from a2.
Iterate through all a2's elements and extract only the ones matching the values inside a1.

```js
var a1 = ["5", "10"];
var a2 = [
  ["10", "2", "10", "E", "5", "5", "u", "0", "5", "10", ":", "5"],
  ["10", "10", "5", "9", "10", "}", "5", "l", "5", "5", "5", "˜"],
  ["x", ".", "d", "2", "|", "[", "z", "8", "s", "d", "2", "5"]
];
var a3 = [];



for (var i = 0; i < a2.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < a2[i].length; j++) {
    if (a1[0] === a2[i][j] || a1[1] === a2[i][j]) {
      a3 = a2[i][j];
      console.log(a3);
    } else {
      console.log("false")
    }
  }
}

console.log(a3)
```

Currently, I have this code. When I check a3 outside the loop I'm not getting what I expected. How can I get the matching values to get into this new array (a3)?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: To print a3 and to get the length of it

Answer (score 0):

You need to do `a3.push` to add element in the array

```js
var a1 = ["5", "10"];
var a2 = [
  ["10", "2", "10", "E", "5", "5", "u", "0", "5", "10", ":", "5"],
  ["10", "10", "5", "9", "10", "}", "5", "l", "5", "5", "5", "˜"],
  ["x", ".", "d", "2", "|", "[", "z", "8", "s", "d", "2", "5"]
];
var a3 = [];

for (var i = 0; i < a2.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < a2[i].length; j++) {
    if (a1[0] === a2[i][j] || a1[1] === a2[i][j]) {
      a3.push(a2[i][j]);

    } else {}
  }
}

console.log(a3);
```

Alternatively you can use `indexOf` & `forEach`

```js
var a1 = ["5", "10"];
var a2 = [
  ["10", "2", "10", "E", "5", "5", "u", "0", "5", "10", ":", "5"],
  ["10", "10", "5", "9", "10", "}", "5", "l", "5", "5", "5", "˜"],
  ["x", ".", "d", "2", "|", "[", "z", "8", "s", "d", "2", "5"]
];
var a3 = [];

a1.forEach(function(item) {
  if (a1.indexOf(item) !== -1) {
    a3.push(item)
  }
})
console.log(a3);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're not adding elements to `a3`, you're simply overwriting the entirety of `a3` on each match found, via

```
a3 = a2[i][j];
```

Instead, *push* it into the array:

```
a3.push(a2[i][j]);
```

Furthermore, your code currently assumes `a1` will never have more than two elements, since you've hard-coded your code to look at its first and second elements only. We can make this more dynamic by asking if `a1` "includes" the given value:

```
for (var i = 0; i < a2.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < a2[i].length; j++) {
        if (a1.includes(a2[i][j])) a3.push(a2[i][j]); //includes() returns a boolean
```

Answer (score 0):

You are directly assigning the matching value to a3 rather you should push the values in a3 array.

Instead of doing this

```
a3 = a2[i][j];
```

Do this

```
a3.push(a2[i][j])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.concat()`, `.filter()` and `.includes()`:

```
let a3 = [].concat(...a2).filter(v => a1.includes(v));
```

**Description:**

- Create a single array containing all elements of all sub arrays using `.concat()` and `spread syntax.
- Filter this array using `.filter()` to select only those elements which passes the filter test.
- Existence of elements in other array can be checked with `.includes()`.

**Demo:**

```js
let a1 = ["5", "10"],
    a2 = [["10", "2", "10", "E", "5", "5", "u", "0", "5", "10", ":", "5"],["10", "10", "5", "9", "10", "}", "5", "l", "5", "5", "5", "˜"],["x", ".", "d", "2", "|", "[", "z", "8", "s", "d", "2", "5"]];

let a3 = [].concat(...a2).filter(v => a1.includes(v));

console.log(a3);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

**Docs:**

- [`Array.prototype.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)
- [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)
- [`Arrow Functions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)
- [`Spread Syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting the value to array. That should be as PUSH method.

If you are trying to use (a3 = a2[i][j]) this will replace your previous values. Please use push method for insertion. Added the code below.
a3.push(10)

The push() method adds new items to the end of an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
// First we flatten the array to get rid of nested arrays
const flattened = a2.reduce((acc, val) => acc.concat(val), []);
// Then we loop through the flattened array and check if the current value (x) exists inside the a1 array - if true -> push to a3
flattened.map(x => a1.includes(x) && a3.push(x))
```

Comment: Add some description of what the code does and that was the fix, thus people will understand better and you will avoid down-votes.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), Array.prototype.concat()][3](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat), [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

Code:

```js
const a1 = ["5", "10"];
const a2 = [["10", "2", "10", "E", "5", "5", "u", "0", "5", "10", ":", "5"], ["10", "10", "5", "9", "10", "}", "5", "l", "5", "5", "5", "˜"], ["x", ".", "d", "2", "|", "[", "z", "8", "s", "d", "2", "5"]];
const a3 = a2
  .reduce((a, c) => a.concat(c), [])
  .filter(item => a1.includes(item));

console.log(a3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce),[`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) and [`Spread syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)(*ES6) to achieve required result.

> ES5

```js
var a1 = ["5", "10"];
 a2 = [["10", "2", "10", "E", "5", "5", "u", "0", "5", "10", ":", "5"],["10", "10", "5", "9", "10", "}", "5", "l", "5", "5", "5", "˜"],["x", ".", "d", "2", "|", "[", "z", "8", "s", "d", "2", "5"]];

var mergerResult = a2.reduce(function(r, v){ 
 return r.concat(v);
}, []);

mergerResult = mergerResult.filter(function(value){
 return a1.includes(value)
});

console.log(mergerResult,'lenght',mergerResult.length);
```

> ES6

```js
const a1 = ["5", "10"];
a2 = [["10", "2", "10", "E", "5", "5", "u", "0", "5", "10", ":", "5"],["10", "10", "5", "9", "10", "}", "5", "l", "5", "5", "5", "˜"],["x", ".", "d", "2", "|", "[", "z", "8", "s", "d", "2", "5"]];

let mergerResult = a2.reduce((r, v) => [...v, ...r], []);

mergerResult = mergerResult.filter(value=>a1.includes(value));

console.log(mergerResult,'lenght',mergerResult.length);
```